# Why is my for loop increment changing dramatically?

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

I am writing a small program for amortization using pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double power(double a, double b);

int main(void)
{
    int loanAmount, number_of_payments, i = 0;
    double interestRate, monthlyInterestRate, monthlyPayment;
    printf("Enter amount of loan : $ ");
    scanf(" %i",&loanAmount);
    printf("Enter Interest rate per year : ");
    scanf(" %lf",&interestRate);
    printf("Enter number of payments : ");
    scanf(" %i",&number_of_payments);

    monthlyInterestRate = ((interestRate / 100) / 12); //AKA 'r' or rate.
    monthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate) * (loanAmount/(1 - 1/(power((1 + 
    monthlyInterestRate), number_of_payments))));

    double interest[7] = {0}; //Arbitrarily set to 7 - assuming less payments.
    double principal[7] = {0};
    double balance[7] = {0};
    balance[0] = loanAmount;
    double *ipoint,*ppoint,*bpoint,*bpointprev;

    ipoint = &interest[0];
    ppoint = &principal[0];
    bpoint = &balance[0];
    bpointprev = bpoint;

    printf("Monthly payment should be $ %lf\n",monthlyPayment);
    printf("# \t Payment \t Principal \t Interest \t Balance \n");
    for (i = 1; i <= number_of_payments; i++) {
        ipoint += i;
        bpoint += i;
        ppoint += i;

        *ipoint = *bpointprev * monthlyInterestRate;
        *ppoint = monthlyPayment - *ipoint;
        *bpoint = *bpointprev - *ppoint;

        printf("%i \t %.2f \t %.2f \t\t %.2f \t\t %.2f\n",i,monthlyPayment,*ppoint,*ipoint,*bpoint);

        bpointprev += i; //Iterates after logic for next calculation.
    }

    return 0;
}

double power(double a, double b)
{
    double i, sum = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        sum = sum * a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and came across an issue where the IDE I am writing in runs the program fine:

on Cloud9 IDE:

[image: on Cloud9 IDE, Correct]

but on a Unix terminal, the increment variable in my for loop jumps after what seems to be an arbitrary count:

on Unix Terminal:

[image: on Unix Terminal, Error]

I am fairly certain it has something to do all of the pointer references I have whizzing around, but I don't know why it would affect the int variable i in the for-loop or why the IDE would handle the error so cleanly. Please educate!

Comment: This is unreadable. Format the code properly.

Comment: Please don't post images of code and/or data and/or results. Instead, please use text. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than incrementing each pointer by `i` in each step of the loop, you should only be incrementing by 1.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, and it was indeed a simple logical error, though this does beg the question of why the IDE is still outputting the correct results/misleading me to think the code is correct.

Comment: Because by pure luck, the memory locations you're accessing beyond the bounds of your array aren't being used by other parts of your code. It's all undefined behaviour though - sometimes your luck will hold out and other times it will fail horribly

Comment: If I may, can I ask why are you using all those pointers instead of, say `interest[i] = balance[i - 1] * monthlyInterestRate;` (I'm not sure what's the exact formula are you trying to implement)?

Comment: @Bob__ Assignment requirements..

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yes, I don't think I thought critically enough about the difference about how the Cloud9 IDE (browser based) would store memory.

Comment: You must check the **return** of `scanf` (otherwise you have no way to know whether you are processing valid data) and `ipoint = &interest[0];` is equivalent to `ipoint = interest;` as the array `interest` is converted to the address of its first element on access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a large number of problems with your code that are just waiting to cause problems. As you have discovered, you failed to protect your array bounds by incrementing your pointers with `ptr += i` causing you to invoke *Undefined Behavior* by accessing and writing to memory outside of the storage for your arrays.

Take for example `interest` and `ipoint`:

```
double interest[7] = {0};
ipoint = &interest[0];
```

So your indexes within `interest` array are as follows and `ipoint` is initialized to point to the first element in `interest`:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
interest    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            ^
            |
            ipoint
```

Within your loop you are advancing `ipoint += i`. On the first iteration of your loop, you advance `ipoint` by one:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
interest    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                ^
                |
                ipoint
```

Your second iteration, you advance by two:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
interest    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                        ^
                        |
                        ipoint
```

Your third iteration, you advance by three:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
interest    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                    ^
                                    |
                                    ipoint
```

When `i = 4` you advance `ipoint` beyond the end of your array, and you invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you assign a value to `ipoint` and attempt to store the value in memory you do no own:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
interest    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | out of bounds |
            +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                    ipoint
```

**Note:** when *Undefined Behavior* is invoked, your code can appear to work normally, or it can `SEGFAULT` (or anything in between), the operation of your code is simply *Undefined* and cannot be relied upon from that point forward.

What you need to do is advance each of your pointers by `1`, not `'i'`. That will insure you do not write beyond your array bounds. You can fix the problem by simply changing `'i'` to `1` for each, e.g.

```
        ipoint += 1;
        bpoint += 1;
        ppoint += 1;
```

There are a number of other places you risk invoking *Undefined Behavior*. You fail to check the **return** of `scanf`. If you input (by accident, or a cat steps of the keyboard) anything other than a numeric value, a *matching failure* will occur, no characters will be read from `stdin` and all further prompts will be skipped and you will then proceed to process with indeterminate value which will invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Further, if you enter more than `7` for the `number_of_payments` or a value less than zero you invoke *Undefined Behavior*. (the results are also rather uninteresting for `number_of_payments = 0`) When taking input, not only to you have to validate the conversion succeeds, but you must validate the resulting value is within a usable range -- to avoid *Undefined Behavior*, e.g.

```
    printf ("Enter number of payments : ");
    if (scanf (" %i", &number_of_payments) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalide no. of payments.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* validate no. pmts in range */
    if (number_of_payments < 1 || number_of_payments > MAXPMTS) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no. of payments exceed MAXPMTS (%d)\n",
                MAXPMTS);
        return 1;
    }
```

Lastly, while you are free to initialize `ipoint = &interest[0];`, it is not necessary. Accessing an array, the array is converted to a pointer to its first element, so `ipoint = interest;` is all that is required. There are other issues addressed in the comments below, but putting it altogether, you could do something like the following to insure behavior is defined throughout your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPMTS 32  /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

double power (double a, double b);

int main (void)
{
    int loanAmount = 0,             /* initialize all variables */
        number_of_payments = 0, 
        i = 0;
    double interestRate = 0.0, 
        monthlyInterestRate = 0.0, 
        monthlyPayment = 0.0;

    /* numeric conversions consume leading whitespace (as does %s)
     * the ' ' in the conversion doesn't hurt, but isn't required.
     */

    printf ("Enter amount of loan : $ ");
    if (scanf (" %i", &loanAmount) != 1) {  /* validate conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid loan amount.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter Interest rate per year : ");
    if (scanf (" %lf", &interestRate) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid interest rate.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter number of payments : ");
    if (scanf (" %i", &number_of_payments) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalide no. of payments.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* validate no. pmts in range */
    if (number_of_payments < 1 || number_of_payments > MAXPMTS) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no. of payments exceed MAXPMTS (%d)\n",
                MAXPMTS);
        return 1;
    }

    monthlyInterestRate = ((interestRate / 100) / 12); //AKA 'r' or rate.
    monthlyPayment = (monthlyInterestRate) * (loanAmount/(1 - 1/(power((1 + 
                        monthlyInterestRate), number_of_payments))));

    double interest[MAXPMTS] = {0};
    double principal[MAXPMTS] = {0};
    double balance[MAXPMTS] = {0};
    balance[0] = loanAmount;
    double  *ipoint = NULL,
            *ppoint = NULL,
            *bpoint = NULL,
            *bpointprev = NULL;

    ipoint = interest;
    ppoint = principal;
    bpoint = balance;
    bpointprev = bpoint;

    printf ("Monthly payment should be $ %lf\n", monthlyPayment);
    printf ("# \t Payment \t Principal \t Interest \t Balance \n");

    /* standard loop is from 0 to i < number_of_payments */
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_payments; i++) {
        ipoint += 1;
        bpoint += 1;
        ppoint += 1;

        *ipoint = *bpointprev * monthlyInterestRate;
        *ppoint = monthlyPayment - *ipoint;
        *bpoint = *bpointprev - *ppoint;

        /* adjust 'i + 1' for payment no. output */
        printf ("%i \t %.2f \t %.2f \t %.2f \t\t %.2f\n",
                i + 1, monthlyPayment, *ppoint, *ipoint, *bpoint);

        bpointprev += 1; //Iterates after logic for next calculation.
    }

    return 0;
}

double power(double a, double b)
{
    double i, sum = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        sum = sum * a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

(**note:** whether you loop from `i=1` to `i <= number_of_payments` or from `i=0` to `i < number_of_payments` is largely up to you, but it is standard for the loop variable to track the valid array indexes to protect the bounds of the array. As above, the *output* for the payment number is simply adjust by `i + 1` to produce the desired `1,2,3...`)

(**also note:** in practice you want to avoid using *floating-point* math for currency. People get really upset when you lose money due to rounding errors. Integer math eliminates that problem)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Will do. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `+= i;` statements in `for-loop` , Change it to `'++'`. When you use `+= i;`  , Too much increment is happening for your **pointers** *(not incremented by **1** but by **i**).*

Modified `for-loop` :-

```
for (i = 1; i <= number_of_payments; i++)
{
    ipoint ++;  // not +=i
    bpoint ++;  // not +=i
    ppoint ++;  // not +=i

    *ipoint = *bpointprev * monthlyInterestRate;
    *ppoint = monthlyPayment - *ipoint;
    *bpoint = *bpointprev - *ppoint;

    printf("%i \t %.2f \t %.2f \t\t %.2f \t\t %.2f\n", i, monthlyPayment, *ppoint, *ipoint, *bpoint);

    bpointprev ++; //Iterates after logic for next calculation. not +=i
}
```

because `+=i` consumes lot of memory *(Too much increment)* causing ***stack smashing*** error.

**Output :-**

```
Enter amount of loan : $ 2000
Enter Interest rate per year : 7.5
Enter number of payments : 6
Monthly payment should be $ 340.662858
#    Payment     Principal   Interest    Balance 
1    340.66      328.16          12.50       1671.84
2    340.66      330.21          10.45       1341.62
3    340.66      332.28          8.39        1009.35
4    340.66      334.35          6.31        674.99
5    340.66      336.44          4.22        338.55
6    340.66      338.55          2.12        0.00
```

Comment: '...+= i consumes lot of memory...'?? Completely BS.

Comment: @Aganju I mean that by `ipoint += i; ` ,  `i` , memory blocks are incremented by pointer `ipoint` which will cause stack smashing. instead of incrementing `i` .